# in_array is returning false while key does exist

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
$int = array (
    1 => "Items1",
    2 => "Items2",
    3 => "Items3",
    4 => "Items4"
);
```

And when I do:

```
var_dump(in_array( 4 , $int ));
```

It is returning: `bool (false)`.
I've read that is caused by the object given , instead of array, but aren't there any solution for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php): Checks if a **value** exists in an array.

You'll want [array_key_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Answer (score 6):

if you want to test the existence of the key use :

```
array_key_exists($key, $searcharray)
```

the `in_array` function test for the value and not for the key

Answer (score 5):

`in_array` only checks the values, thus "Items1".."Items4" in your case. If you want to know if an array has some key, use [array_key_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

```
var_dump(array_key_exists(4, $int));
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because $int does not contain that value.

Your array contains "Items1", "Items2" ...

4 is your key.

If you want to check if key exists, you can use

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

or

```
isset($int[4])
```

Answer (score 1):

`in_array()` checks whether or not a **value** exists in a given array- *not a key*.  4 is not a value in the array, but 'Items4' is.

Answer (score 1):

the integer '4' that you are searching for is a key not a value,

```
var_dump(in_array("Items4",$int));
```

should return true, or if you want to check for the key '4' use Array-key-exists

[php.net Array-key-exists](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)